# how to run django on nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx

I am going through this tutorial - [tutorial](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html)
And could say everything is okay, when I run the server I see the standard nginx page. But - I did everything and should see my Django page. Nginx refers to standard nginx page instead of my folder in `/home/lukp/djangoApp/`

Do you have an idea what I should change ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What is the output `nginx -T` please add that to your question?

Comment: nginx: invalid option: "T"

Comment: `rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default && service nginx restart`

Comment: It's `nginx -t`, no caps. Can you share the nginx conf file you made?

Comment: @JensAstrup, `nginx -t` is to check config and `nginx -T` is to check and dump it to sysout. It may be that a older version of nginx is being used and the flag is not supported on that